# emberjs find then filter

Tags: ember.js, filter, find, ember-data

In emberjs, considering the following data 
(only showing 1 record, normally there would be multiple records):

```
{ "service": [{
    "service-_id":"service_5606ece79bdb05546479739866",
    "service-_rev":"5-62dc477c13ef3ea92869bcdf1a67f1a6",
    "service-company-name":"ABC co.",
    "service-address":"1 2 3 Main Street",
    "service-address-line-2":"",
    "service-city":"asfd",
    "service-state-current":"NY",
    "service-zip":"12345",
    "service-phone":"111",
    "service-fax":"",
    "service-email":"asdf@adsf.com",
    "service-category-current":"web",
    "service-type":"service",
    "id":"service_5606ece79bdb05546479739866"
}]}
```

If I want to return all the records, I can simply do this:

```
App.ServicesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.store.find('service');
    }
});
```

However, let's say I want to return all the records that have the current category as 'web'.  So in the example data, there is this key: **service-category-current**

How would I adjust my model to find **'service'** then filter where **service-category-current** = **'web'**  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way would be to make your API backend handle query params you send to it (so your records would be filtered on a backend, preferably query params could be used to query the database), so response from server would return only records that match your query. Example [`store.query`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_query) call:

```
this.store.query('service', {
  'service-category-current': 'web'
});
```

Which results in fetching records from URL:

```
http://api.com/services?service-category-current=web
```

And you're done. But, if you can't refactor your backend, you could filter records client-side:

```
model() {
  return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(resolve => {
    this.store.findAll('service').then(services => {
      resolve(services.filterBy('service-category-current', 'web'));
    });
  });
}
```

Not ES2015 + using `Ember.RSVP.Promise` instead of native `Promise` (maybe will help you with Safari issue):

```
model: function() {
  var that = this;
  return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve) {
    that.store.findAll('service').then(function(services) {
      resolve(services.filterBy('service-category-current', 'web'));
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: tested the client side code, works great!  thank you for the quick reply!

Comment: spoke too soon, in Safari, I get this error:   SyntaxError: Unexpected token '>'(anonymous function)

Comment: Maybe it's because of ES2015 syntax I've used, I'll update shortly with casual way.

Comment: I've updated answer with using `Ember.RSVP.Promise` instead of native `Promise`.

Comment: it works but it looks like you're filtering client-side?

Comment: Yes, I've mentioned it: "But, if you can't refactor your backend, you could filter records client-side:".